# Jmeter - Assert the response for a single parameter with set of values from array

Tags: arrays, jmeter, assertion

Is there any way to validate whether a specific value is returned within the entire response which we get from Postman tool and set pass/fail conditions. for eg., my URL will be like https://www.testdomain.com/login?memberedu=123 and the specific value I am expecting in the response should be containing any of the following values ie.,'value1', 'value2', or 'value3' and if anything else returned for that parameter then it should fail. I am trying this in parallel with Postman tool also but so far couldn't figure out a proper way to get this validated. [image: Sample Image]

Here, I am trying to validate education value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) (available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, JMeter will automatically extract the `EDUCATIONCATEGORY` attribute value and check whether it is equal to `M.S. (Engg.)`. If there will be a mismatch - JMeter will mark the parent sampler as failed and report the difference:

   [image]

Check out [JsonPath Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) article to lean more about implementing correlation/pass fail criteria for JSON data in JMeter tests.

Also going forward please avoid posting code as image

Comment: Thanks. But, this will validate only 1 value ie., M.S. Eng but It should be pass even if I get M.E & MSc for eg and should fail for any value other than these 3 (M.S Eng or M.E or MSc)